# Error on putting value from TDB Grid to a string VB6

Tags: compiler-errors, vb6

```
Dim ClaimID As String
Dim row As Integer

row = C1truedbGrid.Bookmark
ClaimID = Me.C1truedbGrid(row, "Column").ToString()
```

Error on `Me.'C1truedbGrid'`

> "Invalid qualifer"

I want to put the value of the selected cell in the string, just like calling it in c# winforms.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClaimID = C1trueDBGrid.Columns("Column").Text
```